# Login with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to do a POST action with node.js with a command line application.
The goal is to login to http://hbeta.net
(I want to create a application that post the username and the password automaticly)
thanks ;)

Comment: This question is far too vague, please tell us what have you already tried? show us some of your code...

Comment: Euh i tried this:
var cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper');
cloudscraper.post('http://hbeta.net/', {field1: 'value', field2: 2}, function(error, response, body) {
  ...
});

Comment: (cloudscraper) is a module de skip the cloud flare protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website supports posting data to the login and receiving a login cookie/token back, you can use the following code:

```
var cloudscraper = require('cloudscraper');

cloudscraper.post('http://hbeta.net/', {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
}, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("an error has occured");
    } else {
        console.log(body, response);
    }
});
```

This code will simply send a POST method to `http://hbeta.net/` while bypassing their CloudFlare DDOS protection and send a username and password along with the request.

Comment: Thanks brother ;) that's working

Comment: But with this when he post the connection end, i want the connection to continue ... (sorry for my bad english xD)

Comment: if they don't offer you access to their API or something similar you won't be able to do that.

As a user using a browser you receive a `cookie/token` which keeps you logged in and allows you to authenticate only once.

when you use a POST call unless you manage to store said `cookie/token` and provide it again with every POST call you make, the website will think you are not authenticated.